# Cannot import more than one line from csv file into sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, csv

I am having problems trying to import an entire csv file into a sqlite database. These were my terminal commands:

```
sqlite3 DB.sql
create table table1 (id integer primary key, question VARCHAR(500), Aanswer VARCHAR(255), Banswer VARCHAR(255), Canswer VARCHAR(255), Danswer VARCHAR(255));
.mode csv
.import db.csv table1
select * from table1
```

and the output:

```
7,"Who's head did Courtney Cox say was on her body in Scream 2?","Heather Graham",Oprah,"*Jennifer Aniston","Demi Moore"
```

You'll notice that it only puts the quotation marks around a few fields, which appear to be random... I don't know if this is why it won't move on to import the next line or not.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here are the first few lines of my csv file:

```
1,What movie follows Cher and Dionne named after great singers of the past that now do infomercials?,10 Things I Hate About You,Cant Hardly Wait,*Clueless,Freeway
2,What 90s movie did critic Janet Maslin describe as : A gale-force movie with the energy to blow audiences right out of the theater?,Avalanche,Aftershocks,Armageddon,*Twister
3,What actress declined Neve Campbell's role in Scream?,*Drew Barrymore,Carla Hatley,Courteney Cox,Rose McGowan
```

If I put the quotation marks in myself, it spits out stuff like this:

```
"""What was the name of Milla Jovovich's character in the Fifth Element?""","""Billy""","""Fog""","""Mugger""","""*Leeloo"""
```

Comment: My guess would be a problem with your CSV file. Please post first 10 lines.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite's .import command understands only LF (0xA) end-of line code, not CR (0xD). Check your input file in hex-editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place quotes around the fields with spaces.

Like this

```
C:\Documents and Settings\james\My Documents>type test.csv
1,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'
2,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'
3,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'
4,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'

C:\Documents and Settings\james\My Documents>sqlite3 test.dat
SQLite version 3.6.19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t1 (id integer primary key, q1, q2 );
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import test.csv t1
sqlite> select * from t1;
1,field_with_no_spaces,"'field with spaces'"
2,field_with_no_spaces,"'field with spaces'"
3,field_with_no_spaces,"'field with spaces'"
4,field_with_no_spaces,"'field with spaces'"
```

You will get 'extra' quotes around fields with spaces.  Not a problem.  The important thing is that the entire file is imported, right?

If you care about the extra quites, switch off the csv mode, like this

```
sqlite> .mode list
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> select * from t1;
1,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'
2,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'
3,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'
4,field_with_no_spaces,'field with spaces'
```

Putting quotes around you data, gives

```
1,What movie follows Cher and Dionne named after great singers of the past that now do infomercials?,10 Things I Hate About You,Cant Hardly Wait,*Clueless,Freeway
2,What 90s movie did critic Janet Maslin describe as : A gale-force movie with the energy to blow audiences right out of the theater?,Avalanche,Aftershocks,Armageddon,*Twister
3,What actress declined Neve Campbell's role in Scream?,*Drew Barrymore,Carla Hatley,Courteney Cox,Rose McGowan
```

Comment: I still cannot see the csv file that your are trying to input.

Comment: I tried that, and it appears just like you showed but it will still only import the first line.

Comment: Please post the data you are trying to input.  The data I can see has no quotes protecting fields that contain spaces.

Comment: 'What 90s movie did critic Janet Maslin describe as : A gale-force movie with the energy to blow audiences right out of the theater?',Avalanche,Aftershocks,Armageddon,*Twister

Comment: 'What actress declined Neve Campbell's role in Scream?','*Drew Barrymore','Carla Hatley','Courteney Cox','Rose McGowan'

Comment: I don't think the quotes are the problem, I just don't know why it's only importing one line from the CSV file into the database

Comment: If you post the first few lines of data, with quotes, you are trying to input,  I will take a look.